# Can I have access to the EF 6 Fluent API metadata so I can validate my saves prior to Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework 6, POCO, Code First.

On my `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` I'm using the `modelBuilder` parameter to set up all sorts of metadata, like whether or not my fields are required, max-length and so forth.

```
// please ignore syntax errors. I'm writing this by heart
public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>().Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);
}
```

However, I have a `ContactsService` which has a method called `Save`. `Save` calls an internal method called `ValidateSave`.

**The problem is:** I could easily implement the `ValidateSave` method manually. That would work like a charm. But I really wanted a way to reuse all the configurations I set up on the `OnModelCreating` method.

I know that, if I call the `SaveChanges`, the EF's validation will trigger an Exception with all the information I need. However, I'm mocking the repository layer so I cannot rely of these Exceptions from my Unit Tests.

**Question:** Can I have access to the Entity Framework Fluent API metadata so I can validate my saves prior to Entity Framework?

Comment: Interesting idea.  But wouldn't you end up with the validation being ran twice in production?  Once by your service and then by EF. Maybe it would be better if the mocks ran the validation in unit test so they emulate the real data layer.  Anyway, I'm curious to see if anyone comes up with an answer.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx) article might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GetValidationResult` method:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var myEntity = new MyEntity();

    var validationResult = context.Entry<MyEntity>(myEntity).GetValidationResult();
}
```